# Msgbus - Subscribe to Modifier Changes

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, add-on

I'm trying to subscribe to changes on modifiers of the active object?
I am not very comfortable with the message bus system, so I wondered if this is a limitation of msgbus or if a different path might be needed...

```py
# These are the paths I tried...
subscribe_to_modifier = bpy.context.object.path_resolve("modifiers.active", False)
subscribe_to_modifier = bpy.types.Object, "modifiers"
subscribe_to_modifier = bpy.types.Modifier, "is_active"

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to_modifier,
    owner=self,
    args=(context,),
    notify=modifiers_callback,
)
```

Ideally, I would like to detect all kinds of changes to modifier settings + when modifiers are added/deleted. Currently, I am achieving this with the `depsgraph_update_post` handler.
I am greatful for any ideas or pointers.

Comment: Nobody knows unfortunately since the documentation for msgbus is lacking. You would have to ask the developers. I also have an unsolvable scenario: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283247/how-to-trigger-a-script-after-completing-object-transform